# Awk script Can I assign a variable if a condition using awk command is met?

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk

hi in this simple script  I call a function usage() if there is a cron job owned by root.
Is it possible to do an else statement within the awk, so when the condition is not met I call another function?
Can you please provide an example? 
Thx

```
usage ()
{
# Print usage
       echo "usage function"
} 
#

export -f usage
ps -ef | awk '{if ($0 ~ /crond/ && $1 == "root") {system("/usr/bin/env bash -c usage")
```

Comment: Hi. You should realize that your `awk` script NOT ONLY calls a function IF there is a cron job owned by root -- The usage function is called FOR every running root process having the string `crond` in any part of its command line (a root process as `echo crond` will cause to call the function usage)

Comment: About your question: do you know the ELSE clause in awk?

Comment: If you have a question about assigning variables (as per the question title), would you elaborate on it in the body of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `awk` does allow `else` statements.  In the general form, the `if` statement looks like this:

```
if ( conditional ) statement [ else statement ]
```

As an example:

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /crond/ && $1 == "root") system("/usr/bin/env bash -c usage"); else print "None such."}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using functions, you should create some scripts that can be callable from within `awk`. I don't think you can use bash function like this.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72935/using-bash-shell-function-inside-awk

Comment: I tested his code with the bash function and it works for me.  Normally `system` calls the default shell which might not support it. The OP's `system` call, however, explicitly runs `bash` and that seems to work.